# Extending the C preprocessor to inject code

Tags: c-preprocessor

I am working on a project where I need to inject code to C (or C++) files given some smart comments in the source. The code injected is provided by an external file. Does anyone know of any such attempts and can point me to examples - of course I need to preserve original line numbers with #line. My thinking is to replace the cpp with a script which first does this and then calls the system cpp.
Any suggestions will be appreciated

Thanks
Danny

Comment: Qt used to have a tool called "moc" or something like that, that did something like what you're looking for.  (It actually took a slightly-modified C++ and turned it into normal C++, though, IIRC.)  You'd probably want to do something like that, and maybe give your files (or the output from your tool) an extension that you can use to trigger a rule in your makefile.

Comment: Qt do have its `moc` (meta-object compiler) even today

Comment: If it is literally code injection, what's wrong with putting macro invocations at the point where code injection is needed, and defining those macros in a separate file?

Comment: Explain much more what code injection you want to do, perhaps by giving some concrete example at least.

Answer (score 0):

Providing your modified `cpp` external program won't usually work, at least in recent GCC where the preprocessing is *internal* to the compiler (so is part of `cc1` or `cc1plus`). Hence, there is no more any `cpp` program involved in most GCC compilations (but `libcpp` is an internal library of GCC).

If using mostly GCC, I would suggest to inject code with you own `#pragma`s (not comments!). You could add your own GCC plugin, or code your own [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension, for that purpose (since GCC plugins can add pragmas and builtins but cannot currently affect preprocessing).

As [Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter) commented, you could simply put some weird macro invocations and define these macros in separate files.

I don't exactly guess what precise kind of code injection you want.

Alternatively, you could generate your C or C++ code with your own generator (which could emit `#line` directives) and feed that to `gcc`